# BLE: How to identify last packet for large data in BLE Write and Notify in Win10

Tags: c#, android, windows, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a Windows class library that uses UWP BLE APIs. The setup is:
BLE Host: Win 10 laptop
BLE peripheral: Win 10 laptop or Android

I need to send large file (a few K to a few M) to and from peripheral (using **Write/WriteWithoutResponse** and **Notify**) using custom Service and Characteristics.

For Win-Win, everything seems to be handled by OS. The host just call this once

```
writeResult = await characteristic.WriteValueAsync(buffer, GattWriteOption.WriteWithResponse);
```

with large data and OS seems will auto negotiate for the max MTU (517 bytes on Android) and split the data into smaller chunk and send out.
However, on the receiving side,

```
 private async void Characteristic_WriteRequestedAsync(GattLocalCharacteristic sender, GattWriteRequestedEventArgs args)        {

            var deferral = args.GetDeferral();
            using (deferral)
            {
                GattWriteRequest request = await args.GetRequestAsync();
                if (request == null)
                {
                    Log(LOG_ERR, $"No access allowed to the device");
                    return;
                }
                var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(request.Value);
                string mystring = reader.ReadString(request.Value.Length);
                Log(LOG_VERBOSE, $"Receiving data value length: {request.Value.Length}");
                Log(LOG_VERBOSE, $"Receiving data write offset: {request.Offset}");
                Log(LOG_VERBOSE, $"Receiving data write state: {request.State}");

                
                if (request.Option == GattWriteOption.WriteWithResponse)
                {
                    request.Respond();
                }
                deferral.Complete();
            }
        }
```

Receiver will have multiple callbacks but in each callback, it only has **value**, **Offset** and **state** info. How would the receiver know which packet is the last packet and it can start processing the data?
I don't think checking value length < max PDU size is a good way. And Android and Windows peripheral seems to receive different size of data per packet. (Android 517, Windows 522)

Same for Notify on Win host, it basically has nothing that could tell whether this is the last packet of the whole message.

```
private void NotifyCharacteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
  Log(LOG_VERBOSE, $"Receiving value length from Notify: {args.CharacteristicValue.Length}");
}
```

I though this is very basic requirement and should have implemented by Windows. Am I missing anything here? If there is no Windows native implementation, I need to implement my own mechanism. Using a terminator char at the end of the actual data? Any suggestion?

Thanks,
Angela

Comment: Send a byte count at beginning of the first message and then read until you get the byte count.

Comment: The correct flow is to first note the values and offsets. Then the sender shall send an "Execute Write" on the ATT layer to commit the writes previously sent, and at that time the receiver shall atomically update the value with the new full one. Not sure yet how the last step is to be handled in Microsoft's stack though... With notifications there is no such thing as "full message", since notifications are just sent in one single packet, truncated to fit the MTU.